# Java: How do i split a string, to read commands and call methods?

Tags: java, string, split, command

I am currently making a small Java program which features multiple rooms. 
I am still new to Java so the less complicated the code, the better.

The player has to be able to travel between rooms, but can only do so via the "go (direction)" command, eg: go west.

How do i split this input so i can call my travel method when the player enters "go" as the first part of their input?

At the same time, a direction will need to be registered so the game knows what the next room will be. (Split the second part of the input).

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description the input will be `go west` or `go east` or `go south` or `go north`, suppose if we have string with value `go west`

```
String input = "go west";
```

Then split input string based on space delimiter will return String array

```
String[] dir = input.split(" ");
dir[0] // will be `go`
dir[1] // will be direction `west`
```

Then compare `dir[0]` using `equals()` method, if true call the method with direction

```
if(dir[0].equals("go")){
   //action
   }
```

Comment: I would use String.spit(" +") (empty space followed by plus). Since split uses regex you could handle the situation that someone enters more than one space.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks.EDIT: does it also work with a scanner? if so, do you know how?

Comment: I know, but you should give a try, it's so simple just google it, try and if you stuck at any point post the code i will help you out

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use substring in Java and operate on your commands that way :

```
   String str= new String("quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");

   System.out.println("Substring starting from index 15 and ending at 20:");
   System.out.println(str.substring(15, 20));
```

output:

```
   Substring starting from index 15 and ending at 20:
   jump
```

you could also use regular expressions along with split like this :

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {



        String str = "abdc124psdv456sdvos456dv568dfpbk0dd";



        // split the array using a single digit, e.g 1,2,3...

        String[] parts = str.split("[0-9]");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));


        // split the array using a whole number, e.g  12,346,756

        parts = str.split("[0-9]+");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));

    }
```

link: [using split with regex](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-split-example/)

link : [using substring](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-substring-method-example/)